# Can RosAria and p2os both be used simultaneously for pioneer robots?

Tags: ros, p2os, rosaria, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am currently using RosAria package for the pioneer p3dx on ROS-Hydro Ubuntu 12.04, 64 bit system.
My question is can I use the p2os package as well on the same robot or there will be compatibility and other issues?

If yes, what are the benefits of using either one of the package. I know for a fact that RosAria is a newer , but there are more tutorials for p2os on the internet.
If I can install both, should I install it in the same workspace and catkin_make?
I am new to ROS so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Alex

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198802/can-rosaria-and-p2os-both-be-used-simultaneously-for-pioneer-robots?/) by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 654 on 2014-12-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can install both and switch between them, but only one node at a time can run and connect to the robot controller, both nodes cannot run at the same time.

When either node (any software actually) disconnects from the robot controller any temporary state (acceleration settings, pid settings, etc.) is reset within the robot controller.

ROSARIA will work with more of the ActivMedia/MobileRobots/AMR robots especially the newer ones, but p2os will certainly work for Pioneer 3 and Amigobot.   p2os has been around longer, has more supporting infrastructure built around it like URDF, launch files, examples, and also doesn't require also installing the ARIA library.    I am personally biased towards ROSARIA since its easier for me to support, but recognize that p2os has advantages as well.   They have fairly similar interfaces (I think that the essential stuff at least is identical like cmd_vel, pose, sonar topics) so I think you should be able to switch from one to the other if necessary, by changing topic name references or remapping the topic names.  I don't have lots of experience with p2os though.

---

Originally posted by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) with karma: 821 on 2014-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on 2014-12-03**:
Hi, Thanks for your reply. I am presently having no problems using the RosAria package and it works well with the hokuyo laser range finder. I am however unable to monitor the battery and robot status. Are there any tools to monitor them. Also do you have an idea for powering sensors using Aux point

**Comment by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) on 2014-12-04**:
You can use the battery_voltage topic to check battery use.  Some robots (Seekur, LX) also publish battery_state_of_charge also.  There is no "dashboard" for RosAria like there is for p2os.  For power, see robot manual and ask support@mobilerobots.com if questions.

**Comment by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on 2014-12-06**:
Do the guys at mobilerobots give help regarding ROS for pioneer as well? I mean by the support email.

**Comment by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) on 2014-12-08**:
Use ROS Answers and the sig-ros-pioneer mailing list to ask ROS-specific questions.  For questions about the robot or its behavior (using either ARIA or ROS software), ask aria-users, pioneer-users or AMR support. AMR robot-related questions there are higher priority for us but I also check here.

**Comment by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on 2014-12-09**:
Thanks @ReedHedges. One more thing, we dont have a gyro installed on our p3dx. Which economical external gyro can be used with p3dx?